# Understanding MySQL return

Tags: mysql

The MySQL query is:

```
SELECT orders.scientific_name AS 'Order',
families.scientific_name AS 'Family',
COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Birds'
FROM birds, bird_families AS families, bird_orders AS orders
WHERE birds.family_id = families.family_id
AND families.order_id = orders.order_id
AND orders.scientific_name = 'Pelecaniformes';
```

The Output is:

```
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Order          | Family      | Number of Birds |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Pelecaniformes | Pelecanidae | 224 |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------++
```

But I have 5 **Families** in the DB. Why did it return only one?

Comment: Don't use the old implicit join syntax and See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `COUNT(*)` which turns this into an aggregation query.  Without a `GROUP BY`, this returns exactly one row.

I would recommend getting started by:

- Removing the `COUNT(*)`.
- Replacing the commas with explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.

Then work toward the query you really want to write.  So, to get started:

```
SELECT o.scientific_name AS `Order`,
       bf.scientific_name AS Family
FROM birds b JOIN
     bird_families bf 
     ON b.family_id = bf.family_id JOIN
     bird_orders bo 
     ON bf.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.scientific_name = 'Pelecaniformes';
```

At this point, you can probably add the `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY o.scientific_name, bf.scientific_name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 Families in the orders.scientific_name = 'Pelecaniformes'

then you should use group by

```
SELECT orders.scientific_name AS 'Order',
families.scientific_name AS 'Family',
COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Birds'
FROM birds, bird_families AS families, bird_orders AS orders
WHERE birds.family_id = families.family_id
AND families.order_id = orders.order_id
AND orders.scientific_name = 'Pelecaniformes'
Group by orders.scientific_name ,    families.scientific;
```